# Полю присваивается не то значение!

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть класс Money:

```
class Money
{
private:
    unsigned long rouble;
    unsigned char penny;};
```

Есть конструктор:

```
Money::Money(const double money)
{
    double intpart;
    double frac = modf(money, &intpart);
    if (intpart < 0) {
        ok = false;
    }
    while (frac > 100)
    {
        frac--;
        intpart += 1;
    }
    penny = static_cast<unsigned long>(deleteDot(frac));
    rouble = static_cast<unsigned long>(intpart);
}
```

При передаче допустим 1.2232, выдаёт 1,184. Прошёлся отладчиком, но таки не понял почему так происходит.

Метод `deleteDot`:

```
double Money::deleteDot(double &frac)
{
    int x, value = 10;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string ncbc; //numeral_count_before_comma
    rouble = (int)frac;
    ss << frac - (int)frac; //1.12-1=0.12
    ncbc = ss.str();
    size_t pos = ncbc.find('.');
    if (pos != ncbc.npos)
    {
        x = ncbc.size() - 1 - pos;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
    {
        value *= 10;
    }
    frac -= (int)frac;
    frac *= value;
    return frac;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В этом как раз никакой загадки.

Для 1.2232 ваша функция `deleteDot` возвращает 2232, каковое число при преобразовании в `ungigned char` (хотя вы и пишете `unsigned long`)

```
penny = static_cast<unsigned long>(deleteDot(frac));
```

обрезается до 184.

Как правильно написать `deleteDot`, вы не спрашивали :)

Но намекну - берите дробную часть, не пытайтесь работать со строковым представлением. Умножайте на 100 и округляйте до целого так, как вам нужно.

Comment: А как правильно написать deleteDot?)

Comment: А я намекнул...

Comment: По моему вы не намекнули, а полностью рассказали...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну... я же не написал готовый код :)